# How do i make a function that loops, and changes sprite's position?

Tags: function, loops, cocos2d-iphone, position, ccsprite

so i need a function or something that can make my 2 sprites move up and down, all the time! from the app starts with out anything have been touched on the screen..

heres what i have tryed to do, but since it in my init, it only runs once..
how can i make this loop its self so its looks dynamic ?

```
if (bgSkyer == false) {
            [bg3 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(240,100)]];
            [bg2 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(240,95)]];
            bgSkyer = true;
        }else {
            [bg3 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(240,112)]];
            [bg2 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(240,80)]];
            bgSkyer = false;
        }
```

Comment: How about putting it in while(true) after loading all the UI elements?

Comment: @Adithya `while (true)` is what people call infinite loop,  and you don't want to have it in any programs. At the very least, try `while (flag_var)` instead, or better find another way that does not use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in Jebego's answer, you need to use `CCRepeatForever`. However, assuming you are using `bgSkyer` as a flag to toggle between the two positions, we can use skip that flag altogether if you are using `CCRepeatForever` together with `CCSequence`, as shown below (explicit variables are used for clarity but you can always merge them into one-liners if you want):

```
CCMoveTo *moveTo_240_95 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(240,95)];
CCMoveTo *moveTo_240_80 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(240,80)];
CCSequence *actionsForBg2 = [CCSequence actions:moveTo_240_95, moveTo_240_80, nil];
CCAction *repeatForBg2 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:actionsForBg2];
[bg2 runAction:repeatForBg2]

CCMoveTo *moveTo_240_100 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(240,100)];
CCMoveTo *moveTo_240_112 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(240,112)];
CCSequence *actionsForBg3 = [CCSequence actions:moveTo_240_100, moveTo_240_112, nil];
CCAction *repeatForBg3 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:actionsForBg3];
[bg3 runAction:repeatForBg3]
```

`CCSequence` performs the actions you pass to it one after another in a sequence, `CCRepeatForever` will repeat the sequence forever, until you call `[node stopAllActions]` on the node or until the node is dealloc'ed.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
if (bgSkyer == false) {
    CCMoveTo *moveOne = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(240,100)];
    CCRepeatForever *repeatOne = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveOne];
    [bg3 runAction:repeatOne];

    CCMoveTo *moveTwo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(240,95)];
    CCRepeatForever *repeatTwo = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveTwo];
    [bg3 runAction:repeatTwo];
}else{
    //just repeat code, etc...
}
```

Hope it works!